# My regex pattern does not work

Tags: java, regex

I need to make pattern which will accept String in format `(_,_)` e.g: `"(0,0)"`, `"(1,3)"`, `"(5,8)"` etc.

I wrote condition as following:

```
if (name.equals("(\\d,\\d)")) {
   System.out.println("accepted")
}
```

Comment: `String#equals` does not use regular expressions.

Comment: As stated in the [Regex Wiki FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Flavor-specific meta-information" (third section from the bottom), the only `java.lang.String` functions that accept regular expressions are `matches(s)`, `replaceAll(s,s)`, `replaceFirst(s,s)`, `split(s)`, and `split(s,i)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis with `\`. They have special meaning in regex (for grouping).

You also need to call the correct method, one which matches with a regex, which isn't `equals()`, but `matches()`.

Answer (score 1):

`name.equals()` doesn't actually accept a regular expression.  You're looking for [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), which *will* accept a regular expression.

You'll also have to escape the parentheses, as they have special meaning in a regular expression.

```
if(name.matches("\\(\\d,\\d\\)") {
    System.out.println("accepted");
}
```